# vb.net user input into url

Tags: vb.net, console-application, user-input

I am currently making a VB.net console application that calls upon a web based API to get results back into the console.
What I would like to do is allow the user to input the IP themselves.

```
        Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "http://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q=1.1.1.1"
```

I would like to be able to replace the 1.1.1.1 with a user input

Thank you

EDIT:

When I run the program I need to insert the IP twice into the console

```
  Dim nL As String = Environment.NewLine
    Console.Write("Please enter an IP Address: ")
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
```

This is my code I use to take the user input

EDIT2:
Full Code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

Sub Main()
IP:
    Dim nL As String = Environment.NewLine
    Console.Write("Please enter an IP Address: ")
    'Console.WriteLine()
    Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "http://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q=1.1.1.1".Replace("1.1.1.1", Console.ReadLine())
    Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
    Dim myProxy As New WebProxy("myproxy", 80)
    myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = True
    Dim objStream As Stream
    objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
    Dim sLine As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While Not sLine Is Nothing
        i += 1
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine
        If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, sLine)
        End If
    Loop
    Console.ReadLine()
    GoTo IP
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use -

```
Dim sURL As String
Console.Write("Please enter an IP Address: ")
sURL = "http://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q=1.1.1.1".Replace("1.1.1.1", Console.ReadLine())
```

Comment: Omit `Console.Write("Please enter an IP Address: ")` if needed.

Comment: If it worked, accept the answer and if it helped, upvote it. btw, you're welcome.

Comment: I still need to insert the IP twice in the console

Comment: why twice? <this is because of character limitations>

Comment: your code will take input only once. so what is wrong?

Comment: Well the code gives me 2 times to input anything
Once on the same line at the Console.write
And once on a new line just below

Comment: revise your entire code (in this context) and post it.